# How to add description for each api response data in swagger api doc

Tags: api, swagger

I am creating api using Swagger. My api is working fine. Now what I want is, I want to add description for each data that is returning my api. Suppose here is my api functionality.

```
@SWG\POST(
    path="/api/data",
    tags={"datas"},
    summary="returns all datas",
    description="Base url  is : http://example.com/",
    @SWG\Parameter(
        name="Authorization",
        in="header",
        description="Token to access content",
        required=true,
        type="string",
        default="Bearer TOKEN",
        description="Authorization"
    ),
    @SWG\Response(
        response="200",
        description="Successful operation",
    ),
    @SWG\Response(
        response=400,
        description="Invalid Data| Data not in request"
    ),
    @SWG\Response(
        response=401,
        description="Invalid token | Header Token is missing"
    ),
)
```

This api functionlity returning data like this :

```
{
 "data": [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Title of the file",
  "description": "description of file",
  "content": "content name will be here",
  "thumbnail": "content thumbnail will be here"
}
]
}
```

Now what I want is, I want to add description in the documentation what does `id, title, description, content & thumbnail` means?  In simple word I want to add little description for those. 
I have tried adding `$ref`and `describing responses`. But it is not working. Almost every time I am getting error like this `failed to parse JSON/YAML response`. Please help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have solved the issue .

```
@SWG\Response(
        response="200",
        description="Successful operation",
        @SWG\Schema(
            @SWG\Property(
                property="title = file title",
            ),
            @SWG\Property(
                property="description = file description",
            ),
            @SWG\Property(
                property="name= file name",
            ),
        )
    ),
```